# What does a pair of brackets after class constructor do?

Tags: c++

We have a class of complex number defined with template here:

```
template<typename T>
class complex {
    T _real, _imag;
public:
    // constructor line, with no parameter
    Vector3() : _real{}, _imag{} {} 
    // constructor with pass-in variable
    Vector3( T real_, T imag_ ) : _real{real_}, _imag{imag_} {}

    inline T x() const { return _real; }
    inline T y() const { return _imag; }
};
```

Conventionally I'll expect a semicolon at the end of the line. What does the pair of brackets after the constructor do? And how is `_real` and `_imag` initialized in the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function body definitions are enclosed in `{ ... }` braces... the ones at the end of each constructor indicate a function body that performs no user-provided operations.  In other words, your constructors won't do anything after the initialisation list is actioned.  You could put e.g. `std::cout << "hello\n";` between the braces to "trace" the calls to these constructors.  Using a semicolon instead of the braces would only declare - and not define - your functions; you'd need to provide a definition later and link it in to your executable before or as it runs.

The `{}` usage in the initialisation list - `_real{}` etc. - is a C++11 alternative to parenthesis, and still allows you to specify the value to which that member should be initialised.  In the first constructor, the types will be set to some presumed sane default, which might be `nullptr` or `0` or `0.0` or a user-provided default construction depending on the actual type of `T` used during instantiation.  That contrasts with a constructor that doesn't list the member variable in the initialisation list, or lacks a list altogether, which leaves members without default constructors uninitialised - they must be set in the constructor body or by some other code before they're read from, otherwise there will be undefined behaviour (your program may not work as hoped).

Separately, your class definition must be terminated with a semicolon - after the final `}`.

Answer (score 2):

> Conventionally I'll expect a semicolon at the end of the line.

For a declaration, but not a definition. If the constructor were defined outside the class, and only declared inside, then you'd have a declaration ending with a semicolon

```
Vector3();
```

but in your code, the constructors are defined within the class. In general, you don't need a semicolon to mark the end of a function definition.

> What does the pair of brackets after the constructor do?

If you mean this pair

```
Vector3() : _real{}, _imag{} {}
                             ^^
```

that's the constructor body. It's empty, since all the work is done in the initialiser list.

Answer (score 0):

The pair of brackets after the constructor defines the constructor with no body. The member variables are initialized in the initialization list:

```
: _real{real_}, _imag{imag_}
```

Note that names beginning with an underscore are reserved for the compiler for some cases and should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the constructor here (not only declarating). The second ctor is initializing the class members/attributes _real and _imag in its initialization list.